# What is the version of SSL/TLS in Tensorflow serving

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

For Tensorflow serving 1.7.0, What is the version of SSL/TLS being used. Is it boringssl or OpenSSL? Please let me know the version number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow Serving uses gRPC which in turn uses/can use boringssl. As to the concrete version, are you referring to the TLS protocol versions (i.e. 1.1 to 1.3) or the actual source code revision of the boringssl implementation ?

The latter is somewhat difficult, as there are no named releases of boringssl in the traditional sense.

TensorFlow Serving 1.7.0 seems to use a grpc version that includes the following version:

https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+archive/886e7d75368e3f4fab3f4d0d3584e4abfc557755.tar.gz

I have not found a way to map back from the SHA256 hash (886e7d75368e3f4fab3f4d0d3584e4abfc557755) to  the commit ID in the boringssl/master-with-google branch.

There is some TLS1.3 code in that version of boringssl, but checking against my tensorflow_model_server with SSL enabled (note that the stock Google server does not use SSL at all), it looks like TLS1.2 is in use (which makes sense to the newness of 1.3):

```
openssl s_client -connect my-ssl-enabled-tensorflowserver:myport -tls1_2
```

yields the appropriate "let's use this" response.

Comment: Thank you @Burkhard. I also tried downloading the tar.gz file and extracted it to check the boring ssl version. But no luck. Could you please let me know what TLS protocol version (i.e. 1.1 to 1.3) are we using?